Why was the snake jealous and wanted to marry Chava?
As we know from midrash Bereshit Rabba 18:6 and Rashi to 3:1, the snake was the only animal that could talk, and became jealous when it saw Adam and Chava having relations in the garden. The snake wanted to marry Chava. One lady asked me a while ago: "Every animal in the Garden had a wife except for Adam prior to creation of Chava. Why did the snake additionally want to marry Chava?"
Alternatively, as a the parallel question asks, if the Snake was female and had a husband, why did it want to marry Adam? What is the meaning of this Midrash about Eve in the Garden?
One can certainly explain the story using the words of Midrash haGadol 3:1 about angel S-mael, that it was not a natural occurrence. However, the story in Bereshit does not have details of midrashim, written many years later as ethical teachings, not the documentary of what actually occurred. If the snake could really have relations with Chava, why would Adam let her be alone? Is it possible to explain the story in a way that is straight and reasonable?

There are various Jewish traditions of all animals talking in the Garden

What is your source for the snake becoming jealous of Chava? The Gemoro says it was just Adam he was jealous of?

I'm sorry I got lost jumping from one question to another: 1 "Why was the snake jealous and wanted to marry Chava?", 2 "Why did the snake additionally want to marry Chava?", 3 "why did it want to marry Adam?" 4 "why would Adam let her be alone? " 5 "explain the story in a way that is straight and reasonable?" Can you focus on one question, please?

Regarding Midrashic interpretations, I'm not sure that "we know" is the right phrasing. As you noted, Midrashim frequently contradict each other, as they focus on ethics rather than historicity. So if you ask about some omissions or inconsistencies in the B"R's story, you should probably limit the question to that source: "According to B"R 18.6 that claims so and so, how is that ..." , or "How would Rashi explain the full story, based on his interpretation of so and so". Anyway +1 for the idea.

Thank you. When there are many conflicting interpretations, we can just leave all of them altogether, because none become reasonable to learn from. However we continue reading this story and people ask questions. It's good to have coherence in it.

Netziv writes on Bereshis 3:1

And the serpent was more cunning, etc.: Rashi explained in the name of Midrash Rabbah that it was jealous of them, in that it saw them copulating together and desired her. But this is a wonder! As behold, every creature only desires its species, as it is found in Tractate Bava Metzia 91b: "Its species - it is drawn after its species." And behold the serpent was not lacking its female. And if it was on account of their having intercourse before the eyes of all, the serpent also did not know shame.
Rather the matter is that it sensed that the clinging of the women to her husband was not like its female to it, which only occurred at the time of arousal for copulation. And that is only by happenstance and preparation for the thing. Which was not the case with the woman, who constantly clung to him: Given that she was the bone of his bones, the clinging was even more than a brother and sister. For they too are one flesh. However they are nevertheless not truly so like the first woman to Adam, who was like a limb to the head. And it was jealous of this.
And behold the matter is understood that the serpent never spoke. For if it had originally spoken but was cursed to be dumb and silent, why is this curse not mentioned? Moreover, speech depends on intelligence, and as per Rashi's explanation of, "and so man became a living soul" Genesis 2:7) - with speech and intelligence. And likewise did Onkelos translate, "With a speaking spirit." Behold man was unique in this virtue. However it was the constellation of the serpent that clothed himself with jealousy and spoke at that time from the throat of the serpent.
As every species from all that was created - even the botanic - has a constellation; and that is the angel that is appointed upon that species to protect it and grow it, so that it not cease from the world. And this is like the Sages, may their memory be blessed, said, "You have no [blade of] grass below without its constellation above striking it and saying to it, 'Grow!'"  And the constellation of the serpent was like [the serpent]; as it was jealous of man's clinging to his Creator, may He be blessed. And it is just as we explained in the previous section, that Adam clung so greatly to God, like a portion that always yearns for its source; which is not the case with an angel. It is just separated and it is not clinging and yearning for His light, may He be blessed, except for at the time designated for song and that which is similar. And the angel was jealous about Adam; and the physical serpent about his wife. And [about] that which all of this is not explained in Scripture, the Ramban has already written, in Parashat Bechukotai - and we brought it earlier (Haamek Davar on Bereishit 1:1) - that regarding things that are not grasped by everyone, the Torah only spoke about it by hinting.


I don't know your source for suggesting that the snake was specifically jealous of Chava, but the Gemara in Sanhedrin 59b notes expressly that its jealousy was of Adam for the following reason:

מיתיבי היה ר' יהודה בן תימא אומר אדם הראשון מיסב בגן עדן היה והיו מלאכי השרת צולין לו בשר ומסננין לו יין הציץ בו נחש וראה בכבודו ונתקנא בו התם בבשר היורד מן השמים
The Gemara raises an objection from a baraita to the assertion that eating meat was prohibited to Adam: Rabbi Yehuda ben Teima would say: Adam, the first man, would dine in the Garden of Eden, and the ministering angels would roast meat for him and strain wine for him. The snake glanced at him and saw his glory, and was jealous of him, and for that reason the snake incited him to sin and caused his banishment from the Garden. According to this, evidently Adam would eat meat. The Gemara answers: There the reference is to meat that descended from heaven, which was created by a miracle and was not the meat of animals at all. (William Davidson translation and notation)


Thank you.  I need to research why the question was asked this way. Perhaps books like "Midrash says" or kids versions present it this way.

I could not find a source for jealousy to Chava.  However, the snake wanted to marry Chava, while already being married.  Why?

@YDJ It's in Rashi to 3:1

@shmosel Thank you

In gemara sotah 9b says slightly differently

@YDJ "I need to research why the question was asked this way" is this not your own question?

Someone asked me.
